# Rails One Parent, Two Children, Access Other Child's Attributes Through Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, parent-child

Problem: attemping to develop a cron job or delayed job that delivers autoresponder email messages. Turns out it's a trickier problem that I thought. Here's my model:

```
   class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subscriptions
   has_many :contacts, :through => :subscriptions
   has_many :messages

   class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :contact
   belongs_to :list

   class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user 
   belongs_to :list

         -----------Lists------------
         |                          |
         |                          |
       Subscriptions (join)         Messages
         |
         |
       Contacts
```

My goal is to loop through all subscriptions, and for each subscription check to see if the "days since subscription" matches "days after signup" attribute on the message object. If true, deliver the message to recipient, then continue looping through the others.

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

 def deliver
   @subscriptions = Subscription.all
   @subscriptions.each do |subscription|
         subscription.list.messages.each do |message| 
               if message.days_since == subscription.days_after
                    # deliver message through mailer in a scheduled delayed_job
               else
               end
         end 
    end      
  end
```

If someone subscribed to a list 2 days ago, and the list owner wanted a message to be delivered 2 days after signup, then the message should be delivered because it's a match.

The deliver method above is my attempt to loop through all subscriptions, and compare the subscription.days_since with message.days_after_signiup.

Any advice or ideas would be very much appreciated. Really been struggling with this one, and it would feel great to get through this roadblock.

D.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do something with a where or join statement?

```
messages = Message.joins(:subscriptions).where("messages.days_since > subscriptions.days_after")
messages.each do |message|
    message.deliver
end
```

Comment: I'm going to try adding a deliveries join table between subscriptions and messages. It seems like having a separate first class object makes sense for this. A deliveries model and join table should facilitate an easy nested loop that iterates through all subscriptions, and for each subscription, grabs any messages that have a matching 'days' attribute, and then schedules the email send. Thanks for shedding some light on the problem CreativeReason, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just add a `send_by` to Subscriptions and use the use the range between last_cron_run and Time.now to see if any `Subscription.where(:send_by => last..now)` fall into that range.

I'd also calculate the send_by data at time of subscription.

You can also calculate how to send the next ones this way and your cron job just runs based on 14 minute blocks(00 - 14) and check the minutes of the `send_by`. That's if you set it for 15 minutes.  If not, use whatever you decide to set your timing by, just chop off the last minute of that range (e.g., if an hour, use 59 mins instead).

Comment: Great ideas for the cron_run Pjammer, thanks for taking the time to share your insights.